# Is the direct sum of $p$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\bigoplus_{p} \mathbb Z $ isomorphic as group to direct sum of $p-\{2\}$ copies

Tags: group-theory

Is the direct sum of $p$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\bigoplus_{p} \mathbb Z $ isomorphic as group to direct sum of $p-\{2\}$ copies of  $\mathbb{Z}$

By $p$, I mean indexing over set of all primes.

I think the answer is yes. Let us call first group $G$ and second group $H$.

$$\phi: G\rightarrow H$$defined by $$(b_{1}, b_{2}, .......)\rightarrow (0, b_{2},....)$$

Answer (score 2):

The groups are isomorphic, but the map you defined is not an isomorphism (note that it is not surjective).

Let $P\subseteq\Bbb N$ be the set of prime numbers and $Q=P\setminus\{2\}$.
Then we have a group isomorphism $\bigoplus_P\Bbb Z\cong\bigoplus_Q\Bbb Z$.
For if $\varphi:P\to Q$ is bijection, then we have a group isomorphism $\psi:\bigoplus_P\Bbb Z\to\bigoplus_Q\Bbb Z$ defined by
$$\psi(x_p:p\in P)=(x_{\varphi(p)}:p\in P)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a set $A$ the direct sum $\bigoplus_A \mathbb Z$ consisting of all tuples $(x_a)_{a\in A}$ with only finitely many $x_a\neq 0$ is isomorphic to the free abelian group $F(A)$ by
$$
(x_a)_{a\in A} \longmapsto \sum_{a\in A} x_a\, a.
$$
Given any map $\varphi\colon A\to B$ between sets, we get an induced homomorphism $F(\varphi)\colon F(A)\to F(B)$  by
$$
\sum_{a\in A} x_a\, a \longmapsto \sum_{a\in A} x_a\, \varphi(a).
$$
This defines the *free functor* from the category of sets to the category of abelian groups. In particular, whenever $\varphi$ is a bijection (isomorphism in the category of sets) the induced homomorphism $F(\varphi)$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups.

Hence, let $\varphi \colon P\to P\setminus\{2\}$ be any bijection, then $F(\varphi)$ will be the isomorphism you are looking for.

---

Translated back to direct sums, induced homomorphisms are described as
$$
(x_a)_{a\in A} \longmapsto (x_b)_{b\in B} \quad\text{where}\quad x_b = \sum_{\substack{a\in A\\\varphi(a)=b}} x_a.
$$